# open database when it uses other application

Tags: c#, database, database-connection, firebird

I have a database which uses third-party application. I need to open this database to read.
How can I open the db while third-party application is running?

I get the error:

> I/O error during "`CreateFile` (open)" operation for file

Code:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();

csb.ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded;  
csb.Database = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathToFirebirdDB"];                      

csb.Charset = "WIN1251";
csb.Dialect = 3;
csb.ClientLibrary = @"fbembed.dll";

csb.UserID = "SYSDBA";
csb.Password = "*****";

using (FbConnection fbBD = new FbConnection(csb.ToString()))
{                       

    fbBD.Open();
    // other code
    ...
}
```

Comment: The problem is because its embedded, if you were connectig to a database server you wouldnt have a problem, but what you're trying to do is open 2 copies of a server running the same file.

Comment: @BugFinder: I think, this should be an answer.

Comment: What version of Firebird do you run? Because since 2.5 simultaneous connections to the same db file from embedded servers are possible.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment: The problem is because its embedded, if you were connectig to a database server you wouldnt have a problem, but what you're trying to do is open 2 copies of a server running the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have Firebird version < 2.5

From Firebird embedded v2.5 you can have multiple connections to same DB.